R: How to automate a variable creation procedure where I need to create a separate variable for each level of an existing variable based on ifelse()
I am trying to create a graph with different facets where each facet has the same lines and the only difference among the facets is that each facet highlights a different line (i.e., the only difference is the alpha values of the lines).
Python graph
I was able to create one in Python fairly easily:
time = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
lines = np.array([
    [10, 15, 20, 25, 22],
    [8, 12, 18, 22, 17],
    [5, 10, 15, 20, 16],
    [12, 15, 17, 25, 30]
])

alpha_values = [1, 1, 1, 1]  # Different alpha values for each line
colors = sns.color_palette("coolwarm", len(lines))
markers = ['o', 'd', 'D', 's'] 
line_styles = ['-', '--', '-.', ':']


# Create subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(16, 8))
axs = axs.flatten()

# Plot each line with different alpha in each subplot
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    for j, line in enumerate(lines):
        alpha = alpha_values[j] if i == j else 0.2  # Highlight the line in the current subplot
        color=colors[j] #if i==j else "gray"
        marker=markers[j]
        linestyle=line_styles[j]
        ax.plot(time, line, label=f'Line {chr(ord("A") + j)}', alpha=alpha, marker=marker, color=color, linestyle=linestyle)
    ax.set_title(f'Subplot {i + 1}')
    ax.legend(ncol=1)
    
plt.figure(dpi=1500)
plt.tight_layout()

But I was having a hard time doing the same in R. I was able to do it in R eventually but in a dummy way -- it will get very cumbersome if the base variable has many levels.
In R i did this:
R graph
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:10, 4),
  y = c(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, mean = 2), rnorm(10, mean = 4), rnorm(10, mean = 6)),
  highlight_var = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 10)
)

df = df %>%
  mutate(A_Line = ifelse(highlight_var=="A", 1,0.2),
         B_Line = ifelse(highlight_var=="B", 1,0.2),
         C_Line = ifelse(highlight_var=="C", 1,0.2),
         D_Line = ifelse(highlight_var=="D", 1,0.2)) %>%
  group_by(x, highlight_var) %>%
  gather(alpha_group, alpha_value, A_Line:D_Line)

And then in ggplot2, for the alpha values in geom_line, i just used alpha_value and then facet_wrap by alpha_group
ggplot(df) +
      geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color=highlight_var, alpha=alpha_value)
                        ) +
      scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "purple", "orange", "steelblue4"))+
      facet_wrap(.~alpha_group)+
      theme_minimal()+
      guides(alpha=F)

As you can see, i had to create dummy variables (X_Line) for each facet-- This can get quite hard if the highlight_var has many levels.
Is there any way to create an iterative function to automate the "_Line" variables creation process? Thanks so much!
I tried to write functions using "for" loops but to no avail. I was thinking using grid.arrange to group the outputs but couldn't seem to store the graphs from the loop into an object that can be put in grid.arrange

This function should work:

With lapply()we iterate over each unique value of highlight_var.
Alpha is set for the current group to 1 and 0.2 for all other groups and plots are created.
After keeping all plots in a list plot_list we use grid.arrange() from gridExtra package to display the plots.

library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

plot_list <- lapply(unique(df$highlight_var), function(highlight) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = highlight_var, color = highlight_var)) +
    geom_line(aes(alpha = ifelse(highlight_var == highlight, 1, 0.2)), linewidth = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "purple3", "gold3", "steelblue3")) +
    labs(title = paste("Highlight Group:", highlight)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    guides(alpha = FALSE)  
})


As an alternative we could use gghighlight:
library(gghighlight)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  crossing(facet_highlight = unique(df$highlight_var)) %>%
  mutate(is_highlighted = ifelse(highlight_var == facet_highlight, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, group = highlight_var, color = highlight_var)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ facet_highlight, scales = "free") +
  gghighlight(is_highlighted, use_direct_label = FALSE, unhighlighted_params = list(alpha = 0.2)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("firebrick3", "purple3", "gold3", "steelblue3")) +
  theme_minimal() 



wow thanks so much!! didn't think of creating a list using "lapply" -- out of curiosity, if I wanted to do "facet_wrap" by using the dummy variables - is there a way to create a function for generating the dummies?

Please see my update. Maybe it helps!
